# BizTalk WCF-SQL composite operation for calling stored procedure updates, sequence?

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2013r2

We having a composite operation to invoke stored procedure to update a few tables. But running into some issues now potentially due to the sequence of event the updates are fired. Trying to understand how the composite operation work for WCF-SQL adapter, I know it is using one transaction context to execute the store procedures, but did it honor the sequence of rows when it comes to execute them? (e.g. run 1st row, then 2nd row then 3rd?) Environment is BizTalk2013 R2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the operations in a Composite Operation are executed in order and I've never had cause to doubt this.

Are you having a specific problem?